# How to sort the values in dataframe after carrying out logical operations on the data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting, machine-learning

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

data = [["John",1,3],["Jenna",3,5],["Jay",7,10],["Jose",11,16]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','LL','UL'])
print(df['LL'])
print(df['LL'].values)
desired = int(input("Enter Desired: "))
i = 0
df['Best'] = 0
for elem in df['LL']:
    lowerLim = df.loc[[i],['LL']].values
    upperLim = df.loc[[i],['UL']].values
    print(lowerLim[0][0])
    print(upperLim[0][0])
    if(desired >= int(lowerLim[0][0]) & desired <= int(upperLim[0][0])):
        sortNum = 0
        print("Execute")
    else:
        sortNum = desired - elem
    print(sortNum)
    print()
    df.loc[[i],['Best']] = sortNum
    i = i + 1
print(df.sort_values(by='Best'))
```

Over here even if I enter 2 for desired input even then,
The code is executing the if statement in all elements but expected should be it should run if statement for only first element because 2 > 1 and for all others else statement should be executed. But that's not the case in each elem loop it prints execute thus proving my point that it runs if.

Comment: Can you please provide the current output & desired output for better clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your parenthesis on this line and correct to:

```
if( (desired >= int(lowerLim[0][0])) & (desired <= int(upperLim[0][0])) ):
```

give that try and see if you get expected results. complete trace:

```
0     1
1     3
2     7
3    11
Name: LL, dtype: int64
[ 1  3  7 11]
Enter Desired: 2
1
3
Execute
0

3
5
-1

7
10
-5

11
16
-9

    Name  LL  UL  Best
3   Jose  11  16    -9
2    Jay   7  10    -5
1  Jenna   3   5    -1
0   John   1   3     0
```

Comment: It works but I don't understand that a parentheses in particular can do such a difference

Comment: Search for python order of operations and precedence. Absent doing that, enclosing in parentheses and testing vs not enclosing helps to debug. Good to hear it’s working nonetheless.

Comment: the reason it works is the intrepretor evaluates each condition between the parens and pushes the result on a stack then pops of the results of the conditions for an result